# SQL Server 2012, Not able to restore the database from .bak file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server database on my server and I've taken a backup of it. When I try to restore it to a local machine it is throwing me an error and the process is terminating abnormally,

I have created a new empty database in my local machine and trying to restore the `.bak` into this database with the following code:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Downloads\LiveDB.bak'
```

To get LogicalName for both datafile and logfile and I got the error as follows:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
>   The media family on device 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Downloads\LiveDB.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

What is this error causing?

If this is the wrong way to restore a database from a backup file, can someone tell me the step by step procedure to get it working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, It is a sql server backup file, and I zipped it for transferring from server to my local machine and unzipped it after the transfer. BTW it is the same version of the SQL SERVER

Comment: copied through remote connection from my machine

Comment: No, It was via RDP sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to the server versions being different. You will get this message if you attempt to restore the database from a newer version of SQL Server to an older version - this is not possible to do. To check the versions, run this command on both servers:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Compare the results and make sure the server which you are restoring to is the *same version or newer* than where the backup was taken.

Comment: Not necessarily *newer*, it could be the same version.

Comment: Good call Radu, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was I was restoring from a differential backup instead of a full backup.